# Instance of 'Future<Map<dynamic,dynamic>>' on Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got a problem with my code. I try to show on my App this function that calls a class that has an API request. When I try to print the data returned, it only prints Instance of 'Future<Map<dynamic,dynamic>>' instead of what it is expected (the Magnitud value).

I'm quite new to Flutter, so every tip is well-received and I would appreciate it.

My class is

```
class GaelApi {
  String magnitud;
  String ubicacion;
  String latitud;
  String longitud;
  String hora;

  Future<void> getDatos(int index) async {
    try {
      // obtiene datos
      Response response =
          await get("https://api.gael.cl/general/public/sismos");
      List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);

      Map primerSismo = data[0];
      // obtener las propiedades
      magnitud = primerSismo['Magnitud'];
      ubicacion = primerSismo['RefGeografica'];
      latitud = primerSismo['Latitud'];
      longitud = primerSismo['Longitud'];
      hora = primerSismo['Fecha'];
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      magnitud = 'No se pudo calcular la magnitud';
      ubicacion = 'No se pudo calcular la ubicacion';
      hora = 'No se pudo calcular la hora';
    }
  }
}
```

and what I tried is

```
class _SismosState extends State<Sismos> {
  Future<Map> recabarDatos(int index) async {
    GaelApi instancia = GaelApi();
    await instancia.getDatos(index);
    Map<String, String> datos = {'magnitud': instancia.magnitud};
    print(datos);
    return datos;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 5.0),
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                  title: Text("${recabarDatos(index)}",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17))),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and a picture is this link

[failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h6cN.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: You need to `await recabarDatos(index)`. It's an `async` function, just like all your others. You will probably want to `await recabarDatos(index)` *before* your `return Scaffold(...` call btw, as having `await` inside an expression gets gnarly.

Comment: Also, your `getDatos` function doesn't use its `index` parameter at all - and you shouldn't mutate externally-visible instance state in an `async` method - instead your `getDatos` method should be `static` and return an **immutable** object with data.

Comment: My problem is I want to call that function several times to show different data from the API, according to the index (it is a list of Map types), and the cycle to iterate the index variable is inside the return Scaffold. I think I'm messing everything up lol.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't do that (and as I said, you aren't even using `index` at all right now). Async is generally used for "heavy" or long IO operations (like a HTTP request) which you should initiate all-at-once at the start and await the completion of all requests instead of starting new requests and awaiting each result in a loop - it means your IO will be sequential rather than parallel.

Comment: Also, your `State<T>` class should not be concerned with building a UI - you're criss-crossing your concerns (*separation of concerns* is important!)

Comment: Oh I see. Do you think it is better if I start over? I think I should change my API class to return the entire list instead of a single Map inside that list. It should work better in that way. Thank you for your responses!